# WPF window UI not updating

Tags: wpf, vb.net, user-interface

I am trying to create a dialog box that shows the process of loading certain bill data to Word from a WPF VB.NET app.  The problem is that the WPF UI is not updating to show the change.

WPF Code is:

```
    <StackPanel Grid.Row="1" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" >
        <TextBlock Name="StatusDisplayTextBlock" Text="Printing 30 of 40 to document......" FontSize="20"/>
        <ProgressBar Name="PrintProgressBar1" Height="30" Width="400" Margin="0,10,0,0"/>
    </StackPanel>
```

VB.NET Code:

```
Imports Microsoft.Office.Interop

Public Class PrintingToDocx
    Dim IsWorkDone As Boolean = False
    Public Enum BillPrintMode
        InOne = 0
        Seperate = 1
    End Enum

    Private BrowserBills As New List(Of Classes.BillsNS.BilBrowserClass)
    Private Bills As New List(Of Classes.BillsNS.BillClass)
    Private PrintMode As BillPrintMode

    Private Sub PrintingToDocx_Closing(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs) Handles Me.Closing
        If IsWorkDone = False Then
            e.Cancel = True
        End If
    End Sub

    Public Sub New(ByVal BrowserBills As List(Of Classes.BillsNS.BilBrowserClass), ByVal Mode As BillPrintMode)
        InitializeComponent()
        Me.BrowserBills = BrowserBills
        PrintMode = Mode
    End Sub

    Private Sub Window_Loaded(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs) Handles MyBase.Loaded
        GetBills()
        If PrintMode = BillPrintMode.InOne Then
            PrintInOne()
            ' IsWorkDone = True
        Else
            Dim count As Integer = 0
            For Each k In Bills
                count = count + 1
                StatusDisplayTextBlock.Text = "Writing Bill " & count & " of " & Bills.Count & " to WORD....."
                DataAccessModuleNS.Reports.PrintaBill(k)
            Next
            IsWorkDone = True
        End If
        Me.Close()
    End Sub

    Private Sub GetBills()
        Me.Focus()
        StatusDisplayTextBlock.Text = "Reading Bills Data...."
        Dim count As Integer = 1
        For Each k In BrowserBills
            Bills.Add(DataAccessModuleNS.Bills.GetBill(k.ID.ToString))
            StatusDisplayTextBlock.Text = "Reading Bill " & count & " of " & BrowserBills.Count & "...."
            'count = count + 1
            count += 1
        Next
    End Sub

    Private Sub PrintInOne()
        Try
            StatusDisplayTextBlock.Text = "Writing Bill " & "0" & " of " & Bills.Count & " to WORD....."

            Dim oWord As Word.Application
            Dim oDoc As Word.Document
            Dim oTable As Word.Table

            Me.Focus()
            'Start Word and open the document template.
            oWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")
            oWord.Visible = False
            oDoc = oWord.Documents.Add
            Dim countBills As Integer = 0
            For Each Bill In Bills
                'To Addressing Fields
                countBills = countBills + 1
                StatusDisplayTextBlock.Text = "Writing Bill " & countBills & " of " & Bills.Count & " to WORD....."

    End Sub
End Class
```

The problem is like this:
The functionality if working fine, but the UI is not displaying until all the processing is complete.  Following is the sample image of taskbar at time of processing to word:
[image]

when work is done it is working fine like this:

Following is the Report

[image]

EDIT:  I now used the background worker, but now the issue is that when the progress changed and I try to update the TextBlock on UI thread I get the error that the action on a different thread cannot be done.  Following is the code I used in ProgressChanged event.

```
Private Sub BackgroundWorker_ProgressChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As ProgressChangedEventArgs)
    'Throw New NotImplementedException
    StatusDisplayTextBlock.Text = e.UserState
End Sub
```

Could you please help me in figuring out how to update the UI thread.

Comment: Looks like you are doing everything in the UI thread. You should avoid doing this.

Comment: ok @RichardOD I will try to use BackGroundWorker and update the POST.

Comment: Gosh, that is the LONGEST USELESS QUESTION I have seen in a Long time - ALL the info is in the Edit at the end, the other part of the question just contains ZERO Information relevant. Except a LOT of code and even screenshots. But hey, there is an exception, let's ignore it.

Comment: Well for a newbie, everything is tough, else I can opt to delete to question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to move the logic operation from UI thread...

Best solution would be to use **Backgroundworker** class to separate all operations from the UI. 
Good tutorial on that can be found here [[link](http://elegantcode.com/2009/07/03/wpf-multithreading-using-the-backgroundworker-and-reporting-the-progress-to-the-ui/)]

If by change you can use .NET 4.5, you can simlpy use **Async-Await** pattern [[Async in VB](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/hh191564.aspx)]

Comment: Thank you.  I am in .Net4 and the question is solved, however I got an error that is "the calling thread must be sta"; I will research on it and if I fail, I will post for a solution.  Thank you.

Comment: Just remember that all operations on UI elements need to be done in UI thread. Simplest way is to wrap it with Dispatcher.Invoke(...).